# How to add video.removeEventListener to code

Tags: javascript

Everytime I call the `createResetHandler` I bind the `video.addEventListener` to the same element.

I need to `video.removeEventListener` everytime I destroy the player.

How do I add `video.removeEventListener` to the code? https://jsfiddle.net/yb0tn7p9/

```
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function createResetHandler(player) {
    const resetVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.exit');
    resetVideos.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
        video.addEventListener('click', function resetVideoHandler() {
            player.destroy();
            console.log('hit')
          }
        );
      }
    )
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createResetHandler(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    defaults.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };

    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    players.push(player);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());
```

Comment: Can you just call `video.removeEventListener('click', resetVideoHandler)` before `player.destroy()` ? You've used the `resetVideoHandler` function name twice, if you use that only for the event handler, that should work.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in an answer?

Comment: If you want your event to be called only once, you can pass the `{ once: true }` option to it. (not too sure this is what you want though).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `createResetHandler` function to something like this:

```
function createResetHandler(player) {
    const resetVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.exit');
    resetVideos.forEach(function(video) {
        video.addEventListener('click', function resetVideoHandler() {
            video.removeEventListener('click', resetVideoHandler); 
            player.destroy();
            console.log('hit')
          }
        );
      }
    )
}
```

What I did is to only use the `resetVideoHandler` function name only once for the event handler function and to add the `video.removeEventListener('click', resetVideoHandler)` statement.

Comment: That is not working in the code for some reason: https://jsfiddle.net/o2zn7309/ Click on the Exit button 2 times.

Comment: It should go, 1, 2, 3, 4. Not, 1, 3, 6, 10

Comment: @htmlcssjava3456 What is the expected behaviour ?

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4 is the expected behavior. Inside the console log inside jsfiddle.

Comment: clickHandler is still being called multiple times.

Comment: @htmlcssjava3456 I think that is because you add listeners to the `.exit` buttons every time a player is ready.

Comment: That is what I am trying to fix in the code. video.removeEventListener must not be working, or written properly into the code.

Comment: @htmlcssjava3456 I see, in that case, you should add the click listener only to the exit button related to the player that has become *ready*.

Comment: How do I do that in the code?

Comment: How do I add the click listener only to the exit button related to the player that has become ready? How would that be added to the code?

Comment: @htmlcssjava3456 You can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/np9rzufg/ If you take a look at the modified `createResetHandler` function, the `exitBtn` variable is a reference to the `.exit` button that is in the same `.container` as the player. But still, I cannot see any difference. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, 1, 2, 3, 4 doesn't make any sense to me, I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding event to each element whenever `createResetHandler` is called.
What you should do instead is find the button that is related to that video and call add event listener to only that button.

```js
 function createResetHandler(player) {
    // get the current exit button from the curtain element which's display is set to block
    let exitBtn = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.exit')).find(e => {
        return window.getComputedStyle(e.closest(".curtain")).display === 'block';
    });
    
    if(exitBtn){
        exitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log("hit");
          player.destroy();
        },{once: true}
       );
    }
  }
```

let me break it up a little.
The thing we are sure of is there is only one exit button visible at the moment inside only one curtain whose display is `block` at the moment.

`Array.from` converts the `NodeList` into array so we can utilize the find method of array.
From the button we get the closest (towards the parents) `.curtain` element and check the `display` prop using `getComputedStyle` to see if it is block.

If it is block that means this is the curtain that is being viewed and the button at this iteration is the button that needs to have `click event listener`.

and lastly the `{once: true}` part is to make sure the event is only listened one time. Since you are already using `const` keyword that means you are only going for modern browsers so no need to use `removeEventListener` seperately `{once: true}` will work in all the modern browsers.

updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avwonj91/1/